# How to close idle connections in Spring JMS CachingConnectionFactory?

Tags: spring, jms, spring-integration, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I used the Spring JMS cachingconnectionfactory to improve the performance of the my application based on Spring Integration and IBM MQ. I put sessioncachesize as 10 as we have the max of 10 concurrent threads working (ThreadPoolTaskExecutor) on consume/sending messages.

When I looked at the number of connections opened in MQ explorer (open output count for queue), it shows 10 and it stays on for days and never getting closed.

1. Is there a way to programatically to detect connections which are
   potentially stale - say idle for half a day - I checked the
   resetConnection() but not sure how to get the last used time for the
   session.
2. Does Spring provides any connection time out parameter for
   cacheconnection factory? or How to release these idle connections?

Also, the heartbeat/keepalive mechanism will not work for us as we want to physical close the cached connections based on last used time.

Comment: Something else must be going on; `CachingConnectionFactory` is a subclass of `SingleConnectionFactory`. There is __only one connection__ from each factory; the sessions are cached within that connection.

Comment: The number output counts/connections in MQ explorer is the number of connection handles created by the IBM MQ classes. Per IBM documentation, A JMS Session object encapsulates an IBM MQ connection handle, which therefore defines the transnational scope of the session.

Since the session cache size was 10 in my application, there were 10 MQ connections handles created (one for each session) stayed open for days and was inactive.
Can we attach a session timeout to cachedsessions in CCF?
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031960_.htm

Comment: My application requires a session timeout for cachedsessions in CCF. We would like to remove the sessions from cache and physical close if it is incactive/unused for a period of time. I am not sure if Spring provides option for attaching timeout to a session or exposing the last time session is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the timeout is a property of the `Session` object returned by IBM, you could subclass the connection factory, override `createSession()`; call `super.createSession(...)` then set the property before returning it.

You might also have to override `getSession(...)` and keep calling it until you a get a session that is not closed. I don't see any logic to check the session state in the standard factory. (`getSession()` calls `createSession()` when the cache is empty).

Comment: we have 100+ destinations;for every send, a session is returned from cache, it adds a producer to its own cache. Reusing the same producer is not happening most of the time as there is no guarantee that same session being returned by cache when sending to same destination next time. For every producer, IBM creates the connection handle and 1000+ mq connections staying open without being reused (10 sessions * 100+ destinations). Spring has the dynamic proxy impl for handling producer cache which is making things complex to implement closing strategy for producers.

Comment: Maybe you could use a `ThreadLocal`; have the calling thread load it up with the destination before calling the template; then you could cache a session (or sessions) per destination.